# The inventory for different slots keep merging

Tags: python

Im currently working on a python assignment based on a choice based game.
The user has 3 slots in which they can place their progress, inventory and etc.
In theory each slot should keep their own value but it does not work. The values for 'pwr' and 'cash' keep adding up

the code i attached is still in progress and i have just started learning code, so theres alot of blanks, open ends and errors. the issue im having can be noticed under scene 1 when the code prints the pwr and cash that the character has.

here is the code

```
import json
import time
import random

# Function to load user data from a JSON file
def load_user_data():
    try:
        with open('users.json') as file:
            user_data = json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        user_data = {}
    return user_data


# Function to save user data to a JSON file
def save_user_data(user_data, username):
    with open('users.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(user_data, file)



def print_lines_with_delay(lines, delay):
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        time.sleep(delay)


# Function for user registration
def sign_up():
    print("\n-SIGN UP-")
    print("Return > 0")

    fname = input("Enter your name: ")
    mail = input("Enter your email address: ")
    while True:
        # Prompts user to enter their username
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        user_data = load_user_data()

        # Check if the user wants to exit
        if username == "0":
            return None

        if username in user_data:
            print("Username already in use.")
            print("Please log in or choose a different username")
        else:
            # Enables a loop that continues until all conditions are met
            while True:
                # Informs the user about the password requirements
                print("\nPlease ensure your password has a minimum of 8 characters.")
                # Prompts user to enter their password of choice
                password = input("Enter your password: ")
                if password == "0":
                    return None
                # Displays the length of the password entered by the user
                print("\nPassword length:", len(password), "characters")

                if len(password) < 8:
                    # Displays the following message if the password entered does not meet the requirements
                    print("\nPassword is too short. Please try again.")
                    # The program will loop if the password does not meet the requirements
                    continue

                # Prompts the user to re-enter their password for confirmation
                confirm = input("\nConfirm your password: ")

                # Compares both passwords to check if they are the same
                # Displays the following message if the passwords do not match
                if password != confirm:
                    print("\nPasswords do not match. Please try again.")
                    # The program will loop if the passwords do not match
                    continue

                # Update the user_data dictionary with the new user information
                user_data = {
                    username: {
                        'password': password,
                        'username': username,
                        'fname': fname,
                        'mail': mail,
                        'character': {
                            'slot1': {
                                'cname': '',  # Add 'cname' key with an initial empty string value
                                'lives': 3,
                                'q_anger': 0,
                                'inventory': [],  # Add 'inventory' key with an empty list as the initial value
                                'progress': 'start',  # Add 'progress' key with an initial value
                                'cash': 0,  # Add 'cash' key with an initial value
                                'pwr': 0  # Add 'pwr' key with an initial value
                            },
                            'slot2': {
                                'cname': '',  # Add 'cname' key with an initial empty string value
                                'lives': 3,
                                'q_anger': 0,
                                'inventory': [],
                                'progress': 'start',
                                'cash': 0,
                                'pwr': 0
                            },
                            'slot3': {
                                'cname': '',  # Add 'cname' key with an initial empty string value
                                'lives': 3,
                                'q_anger': 0,
                                'inventory': [],
                                'progress': 'start',
                                'cash': 0,
                                'pwr': 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                save_user_data(user_data, username)
                # Displays the success message if all password requirements are met
                # Displays a welcome message for the user
                print("\nUsername and password successfully set!")
                print("Welcome", username, "!")
                # The loop ends as all conditions are met
                break

        # Break the outer loop if the username is successfully registered
        if username not in user_data:
            break
        break


# Function for user login
def login():
    while True:
        print("\n -LOGIN-")
        print("Return > 0")

        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        # Check if the user wants to exit
        if username == "0":
            return None

        print("Forgot Password? > 1")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        # Check if the user wants to exit
        if password == "0":
            return None
        if password == "1":
            reset_password()

        user_data = load_user_data()
        if username in user_data and user_data[username]['password'] == password:
            print(f"\nWelcome back, {username}!")
            return username
        else:
            print("Incorrect username or password. Please try again.")


def reset_password():
    print("\n-RESET PASSWORD-")
    print("Main Menu > 0")

    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username: ")

        # Check if the user wants to exit
        if username == "0":
            return None

        user_data = load_user_data()
        if username in user_data:
            print(f"\n{user_data[username]['username']}")
            print(f"{user_data[username]['fname']}")
            print(f"{user_data[username]['mail']}")

            while True:
                # Similar coding to the Sign-up process
                new_password = input("\nEnter your new password: ")
                print("\nPassword length:", len(new_password), "characters")

                if len(new_password) < 8:
                    print("\nPassword is too short. Please try again.")
                    continue

                password_confirm = input("\nConfirm your password: ")

                if new_password != password_confirm:
                    print("\nPasswords do not match. Please try again.")
                    continue

                user_data[username]['password'] = new_password
                save_user_data(user_data, username)
                print("Password reset successful")
                break

            break
        else:
            print("Invalid username. Please try again.")


def slot_data(user_data, username):
    for choice in range(1, 4):
        slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
        if slot['cname']:
            print(f"Slot {choice}: {slot['cname']}")
        else:
            print(f"Slot {choice}: Empty")


def new_journey(user_data, username):
    slot_data(user_data, username)

    slot_number = input("Select a slot (1, 2, or 3) or enter '0' to go back: ")
    if slot_number == '0':
        return

    if slot_number in ['1', '2', '3']:
        slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{slot_number}']
        if not slot['cname']:
            cname = input("Enter your character name: ")
            slot['cname'] = cname
            slot['lives'] = 3
            slot['q_anger'] = 0
            slot['inventory'] = []
            slot['progress'] = 'start'
            slot['cash'] = 0
            slot['pwr'] = 0
            print(f"Character '{cname}' saved in slot {slot_number}.")
            save_user_data(user_data, username)
            start_story(user_data, username, slot_number)
        else:
            overwrite = input(f"Slot {slot_number} already contains a character. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n): ")
            if overwrite.lower() == 'y':
                cname = input("Enter your character name: ")
                slot['cname'] = cname
                slot['lives'] = 3
                slot['q_anger'] = 0
                slot['inventory'] = []
                slot['progress'] = 'start'
                slot['cash'] = 0
                slot['pwr'] = 0
                print(f"Character '{cname}' overwritten in slot {slot_number}.")
                save_user_data(user_data, username)
                start_story(user_data, username, slot_number)
            else:
                print("No changes made.")
    else:
        print("Invalid slot selection.")



def continue_journey(user_data, username, choice):
    print("-JOURNEY SLOTS-")
    for slot_number in range(1, 4):
        slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{slot_number}']
        if slot is not None:
            print(f"Slot {slot_number}: {slot['cname']}")

    choice = input("Select a slot (1, 2, or 3) to continue or enter '0' to go back: ")
    if choice == '0':
        return

    if choice in ['1', '2', '3']:
        slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
        if slot is not None:
            print(f"Continuing your story in Slot {choice}.")
            # Call a function to continue the story for the selected slot
        else:
            print(f"No character found in Slot {choice}.")
    else:
        print("Invalid slot selection.")


item_data = [
    ("ssword", "Silver Sword", 20, 20, 5),
    ("sarmour", "Silver Armour", 20, 0, 20),
    ("obow", "Oak Bow", 20, 20, 5),
    ("hide", "Thick Leather Hide", 20, 0, 20),
    ("staff", "Mystical Staff", 20, 15, 10),
    ("robe", "Novice Robe", 20, 0, 20),
]

items = {}
for item_id, name, cash, atk, defense in item_data:
    items[item_id] = {
        "name": name,
        "cash": cash,
        "atk": atk,
        "def": defense
    }

def roll():
    random_number = random.randint(0, 9)
    return random_number


def adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items):
    if item_id in items:
        item_name = items[item_id]['name']
        character_slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
        character_slot['inventory'].append(item_id)

        if 'pwr' not in character_slot:
            character_slot['pwr'] = 0
        if 'cash' not in character_slot:
            character_slot['cash'] = 0

        # Update combat power based on the newly added item
        character_slot['pwr'] += items[item_id]['atk'] + items[item_id]['def']

        # Update cash value
        character_slot['cash'] += items[item_id]['cash']

        print(f"\n{character_slot['cname']} is now worth {character_slot['cash']}")
        print(f"The item '{item_name}' has been added to inventory.")
        print(f"Combat power for {character_slot['cname']} is: {character_slot['pwr']}")
    else:
        print(f"The item with ID '{item_id}' does not exist.")



# Function to display the menu
def display_menu():
    print("\n   DESTINY TALES")
    print("\033[3mThe Interactive Saga\033[0m")
    print("New Journey       > 1")
    print("Continue Journey  > 2")
    print("Log out           > 3")


# Function to start a new story
def start_story(user_data, username, choice):
    slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
    story_progress = slot.get('progress', 'start')

    print(f"\nWelcome {user_data[username]['username']} to DESTINY TALES!!")
    print("This is an interactive adventure comic book. The first of it's kind!")
    print("To progress through the story all you have to do is enter the number keys in accordance to the options given.")
    print("Each choice you make has an impact on your adventure, so choose your steps wisely.")
    print("We hope you enjoy your time here!")
    print("\nAUTOSAVE is turned ON")
    print("If you wish to exit to the main menu at any point, press any other key than indicated.")
    print("Press any key to continue")
    input()

    character_slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
    if story_progress == 'start':
        message = [
            "\nYou see nothing",
            "You hear nothing",
            "You feel something...",
            "\nThere is a rock in your hand with carvings on it",
            "You press the mysterious rock and a BRIGHT FLASH occurs",
            "Vision is restored. You seem to be in a thick forest",
            "\nA voice bellows from above",
            f"\n'Arise, {character_slot['cname']}! Let's start your adventure in this new world!'",
            "'I have given you 3 lives! Be sure not to waste them!'",
            "'The path ahead may be scary but I have faith in you!'",
            "'Now, pick up the weapon and begin your legend!'",
            "'GOOD LUCK!!'",
            "\nYou look down and see a Knight's Sword"
            ]
        delay = .25

        # Call the function multiple times with different messages
        print_lines_with_delay(message, delay)

        print("Pick it up > 1")

        choice = input("--> ")

        if choice == '1' or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene1':
            item_id = "ssword"
            adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items)
            item_id = "sarmour"
            adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items)

            message1 = [
                "\nYou are rudely awakened by the sound of calamity",
                "A commanding voice beckons, 'KNIGHTS OF HOGWANIA, FORM UP!!",
                "The voice comes from Leader Harrison",
                "\nA royal figure then walks down the stairs",
                "\nLeader Harrison shouts again, 'SALUTE THE QUEEN!!'",
                "You find yourself saluting the Queen along with your fellow comrades",
                "\nThe Queen pleads all of you to go save the King",
                "'Knights of Hogwania, please adhere to your duty. Save your King from those terrible goblins!'",
                "'Very well Your Majesty, we will not return until we succeed,' Leader Harrison responds. 'KNIGHTS!! ONWARDS!!'",
                "\nAs your fellow knights march along, you are there standing, unsure of what to do",
                "There are slight feelings of confusion as you are still adjusting to your new surroundings",
                "'The Queen notices your confused state and asks you, 'Are you alright?'",
                "\nWhat do you respond?",
            ]
            delay1 = .25
            print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

            print("'Who are you??'     > 1")
            print("'Yes Your Majesty!' > 2")
            print(" Options            > 3")

            choice = input("--> ")
            save_user_data(user_data, username)

            if choice == '1' or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene2':
                message1 = [
                    "\nWho are you?? Where am I? What is this place??",
                    "\nThe Queen's face turns red with anger",
                    "'WHAT NONSENSE? You DARE question your Queen?!?' she scoffs,",
                    "'Go now, before I send to you prison', she threatens",
                    "\n(The Queen will remember this conversation)",
                ]
                delay1 = .25
                print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

                character_slot['progress'] = 'scene3'
                character_slot['q_anger'] += 1
                save_user_data(user_data, username)

            if choice == '1' or choice == '2' or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene3':

                message1 = [
                    "\nYou hurriedly run to catch up with the rest of the knights",
                    "You arrive at the goblin village",
                    "\n'CHARGE THE CAPITAL!!' screams Leader Harrison",
                    "\nThe Knights of Hogwania storm the capital",
                     "Being the last knight to enter, you find yourself between two paths",
                ]
                delay1 = .25
                print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

                print("\nWhich path do you choose?")
                print("Left    > 1")
                print("Right   > 2")
                print("Options > 3")
                choice = input("--> ")


                save_user_data(user_data, username)

                if choice == '1' or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene4':

                    message1 = [
                        "\nYou run to the left",
                        "Eventually, you reach a dark area. It gives off a creepy vibe.",
                        "'OVER HERE!' the King calls. You look at the direction of the voice",
                        "The King is chained to the wall. You rush to release him",
                        "\n\033[3mBONK\033[0m",
                        "\nYou are blocked by the GOBLIN LORD",
                        "'Hrmpph! Prepare for battle!', it growls",
                    ]
                    delay1 = .25
                    print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

                    enemy_pwr = 50
                    print("-BATTLE-")
                    print(f"\n{character_slot['cname']}:{character_slot['pwr']}")
                    print(f"Lives: {character_slot['lives']}")
                    print(f"Goblin Lord: {enemy_pwr}")
                    print("\nAttack > 1")
                    choice = input("--> ")

                    save_user_data(user_data, username)

                    if choice == '1':

                        roll()
                        random_number = roll()
                        if random_number in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
                            character_slot['pwr'] += random_number + 1
                        elif random_number in [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
                            enemy_pwr += random_number % 5 + 1
                        print(f"\nThe die landed on, {random_number}")
                        print(f"{character_slot['cname']}:{character_slot['pwr']}")
                        print(f"Goblin Lord: {enemy_pwr}")

                        if character_slot['pwr'] < enemy_pwr or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene5':
                            character_slot['lives'] -= 1

                            print("\n-LOSS-")
                            print(f"Lives: {character_slot['lives']}")

                            message1 = [
                                "\nThe Goblin Lord clobbers you",
                                "Backup soon arrives and together, The Knights of Hogwania defeat the Goblin Lord",
                                "After releasing the King, you and your comrades make your way home",
                                "They laugh at your attempt to take on the Goblin Lord alone",
                            ]
                            delay1 = .25
                            print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

                            print("Go back to Hogwania > 1")
                            choice = input("--> ")

                            if choice == '1':
                                print("wait")
                            else:
                                print("Where are you going? Go back home")

                        elif character_slot['pwr'] > enemy_pwr or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene6':
                            print("\n-VICTORY-")
                            print(f"Lives: {character_slot['lives']}")
                            message1 = [
                                "\nYou slay the Goblin Lord",
                                "The other knights enter the room as you free the King from his shackles",
                                "They stare in amazement of your feat",
                                "The King praises you, 'Well done! You will be rewarded handsomely'",
                                "You join the rest of the knights as they make their way home",
                                "Leader Harrison congratulates you"
                            ]
                            delay1 = 0
                            print_lines_with_delay(message1, delay1)

                        print("Go back to Hogwania > 1")
                        choice = input("--> ")

                        if choice == '1':
                            print("wait")
                        else:
                            print("Where are you going? Go back home")
            if choice == '3':
                print('Black thunder strikes and you are dead')

        else:
            print("You close your eyes and go back to sleep")


# Main program loop
while True:
    print("\n   DESTINY TALES")
    print("\033[3mThe Interactive Saga\033[0m")
    print("    Sign up > 1")
    print("    Login   > 2")
    print("    Exit    > 3")
    print("Please use the number keys to navigate around")
    choice = input("Enter key: ")

    if choice == '1':
        sign_up()
    elif choice == '2':
        username = login()
        if username:
            while True:
                display_menu()
                user_data = load_user_data()
                menu_choice = input("Enter key: ")
                if menu_choice == '1':
                    new_journey(user_data, username)
                elif menu_choice == '2':
                    continue_journey(user_data, username, choice)
                elif menu_choice == '3':
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
    elif choice == '3':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")
```

im not sure if i put it in the correct format for this post. its huge
so what im expecting is for example

log in, then new adventure, then choose slot 1, then name character, then eventually in scene 1, it should print
cname is now worth 20
The item 'Silver Sword' has been added to inventory.
Combat power for 78 is: 25

cname is now worth 40
The item 'Silver Armour' has been added to inventory.
Combat power for 78 is: 45

and then if you exit and choose slot 2, create a new character, and then same thing, new values,

but instead, after creating data in slot 1, then choosing slot 2 for a new data, this will be printed,
cname is now worth 60
The item 'Silver Sword' has been added to inventory.
Combat power for 78 is: 70

cname is now worth 80
The item 'Silver Armour' has been added to inventory.
Combat power for 78 is: 90

thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: There is a lot to go over here, it is going to be hard to find the issue without refactoring the code. (For example, neither of the `while True` conditions in the `sign_up` fonction are useful, or the 11 lines of character initialization in the `new_journey` function that are duplicated). I read over it but could not find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

```
    if choice == '1' or character_slot['progress'] == 'scene1':
        item_id = "ssword"
        adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items)
        item_id = "sarmour"
        adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items)
```

You're passing `choice` (which is always 1) as the third argument to `adding()`.

However, that function uses the third argument as the **character slot**:

```
def adding(user_data, username, choice, item_id, items):
    if item_id in items:
        item_name = items[item_id]['name']
        character_slot = user_data[username]['character'][f'slot{choice}']
        character_slot['inventory'].append(item_id)
```

So it's always using the item data in character slot 1.